# Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2

Tags: компиляция, машинное-обучение, tensorflow

Получаю постоянно следующую ошибку в окне консоли Jupiter Notebook:

**2018-05-31 16:39:04.994528: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2**

Как задействовать возможность выполнения инструкций в TF установленного через дистрибутив Anaconda ?

Comment: ОС: Windows 10,
Мой CPU: i5-7200U

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы используете GPU, то в общем случае это предупреждение вас не касается. Выключить его можно так:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
```

Если вы работаете без GPU, то [можно попробовать собрать TensorFlow из исходников](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources).

Comment: Спасибо за рекомендацию